# can't convert video to mp4 on centos with ffmpeg since update to 3.4.9

Tags: ffmpeg

I have just updated ffmpeg on centos 7 to version 3.4.9, i am having issues since the update converting mov to mp4, it keeps giving me the following error and i'm not sure how to solve it

> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x831ec0] moov atom not found
> /home/user/api/private_uploads/chat/3d721e80-3a70-11ec-a302-b7cf4598d93b.mov:
> Invalid data found when processing input

**EDIT**

I uninstalled the libraries it mentions above and the correct version installed, but i still get the same problem with 3.2.4!

Answer (score 0):

Try to skip the check signature with this command:

```
yum install --nogpgcheck ffpmeg-3.2.4
```

Comment: It says it's already installed, but when i actually ran the install the error i pasted happened. Package matching ffmpeg-3.2.4-1.el7.centos.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update. The thing is when i run ffmpeg -version it shows 3.4.9 not 3.2.4

Comment: i have uninstalled it completely and tried to reinstall as per your suggestion and now i'm getting conflicts. I've edited my post above.

Comment: Thanks for your input I’ve answered my own question. I was simply trying to convert the file before the upload had finished

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the video file was being corrupted when uploading with node. I changed the following:

> fs.writeFile(pathToFile,data.file.file,()=>{});

To:

> fs.writeFileSync(pathToFile,data.file.file);

And it's now all working. I think what was happening was i was using async and trying to convert the file before it finished uploading/writing to the file